# webpack-streams breaks @types/webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-stream

I have a gulpfile that I'm building with typescript. Everything is working until I add `@types/webpack-stream`, then for some reason I get a really ugly error:

```
node_modules/@types/webpack-stream/index.d.ts:23:24 - error TS2694: Namespace 'exports' has no exported member 'Compiler'.

23     callback?: webpack.Compiler.Handler,
                          ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:32:3 - error TS2305: Module '"tapable"' has no exported member 'Tapable'.

32   Tapable,
     ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1081:23 - error TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

1081             resolver: SyncWaterfallHook;

...
[lots of other types not working here]
...

Found 90 errors.
```

Below is my `package.json`

```json
{
    "type": "module",
    "engines": {
        "node": "^16.12.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "tsc --watch",
        "gulp": "yarn gulp:build && yarn gulp:run",
        "gulp:build": "tsc --project gulp",
        "gulp:run": "gulp"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "highlight.js": "^11.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.15.7",
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.15.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs": "^7.15.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd": "^7.14.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
        "@types/gulp": "^4.0.9",
        "@types/gulp-babel": "^6.1.30",
        "@types/gulp-if": "^0.0.34",
        "@types/gulp-rename": "^2.0.1",
        "@types/gulp-sourcemaps": "^0.0.35",
        "@types/gulp-terser": "^1.2.1",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.5",
        "@types/webpack-stream": "^3.2.12",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
        "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-terser": "^2.1.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
        "rambda": "^6.9.0",
        "typescript": "^4.4.4",
        "webpack": "^5.61.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
        "webpack-stream": "^7.0.0"
    }
}
```

Before I add that package everything works, I was considering not adding it but TS screams at me because:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'webpack-stream'. '/node_modules/webpack-stream/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/webpack-stream` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'webpack-stream';`ts(7016)`
```

But when I add it, it just doesn't want to work. I tried re-defining the first error at `node_modules/@types/webpack-stream/index.d.ts:23:24` to see if it was that was everything like this:

```js
    callback?: Parameters<webpack.Compiler["run"]>[0] | Parameters<webpack.Compiler["watch"]>[1]
```

which **did** fix that first error, but the rest stay there. I'm not sure where to go from here, I *could* re-implement `webpack-streams` in TS ig...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

First, going to [`@types/webpack-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webpack-stream), under dependencies we get  `@types/webpack` and `@types/node`.

I already had `@types/node` installed for a different reason, so:

- removed `@types/webpack-stream`
- added `@types/webpack`
- added `@types/webpack-stream` back again (to make sure that pnp is resolving to the `@types` version I want)

---

On top of this I have `gulp/` directory where I keep my `gulpfile.ts`, I made sure that the `tsconfig.json` had the following:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```